# Timeout during committing a transaction

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactions

I have an issue during committing a transaction. All changes performed in transaction block are committed to database but I cannot get positive feedback on application side that transaction was finished successfully.

Because of that my application is in dirty state. It thinks that previous operation wasn't performed successfully, so it blocks next actions.

How to prevent such situations? How can I confirm that all actions within transaction was finished successfully?

This is a stack trace I have:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Commit()
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't increase the timeout?

Comment: Interesting if unusual problem -- ideally a `COMMIT` should take very little time, because the engine optimizes for the situation where transactions will get committed. [This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26d54516-74b7-4a54-b879-85536e4b605f/where-to-set-the-timeout-for-a-sqltransactioncommit?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) has some discussion, with no resolution. There is no separate setting for the commit timeout, so you can't choose to wait indefinitely for that (but not individual commands).

Comment: Note that the default command timeout is 30 seconds. If you aren't changing that, and your commits take *30 seconds*, you should take a good look at your server, because that really is unusually long. You may be suffering from nasty stuff like transaction log fragmentation, or a flaky network, even a hardware issue. Fixing these issues won't fix the general fact that a successful commit might be lost client-side, but they're still very much worth fixing.

Comment: Another option is a *client* problem -- if the machine is overloaded, the client may not process the server response in time. Again, if it can't do that in 30 seconds, that's not a good thing.

Comment: I don't want to increase the timeout. It is not a solution for me. And agree that it might be related with some hardware / network, etc. But how should I handle such situation on application side? - that is the main question here.

Comment: Short of waiting forever, you *can't*, that's the point. If you are willing to wait forever: pass a unique value from the client to the server that it stores persistently after all command but before the final `COMMIT`. If the client gets a timeout exception on the commit (and *only* then!) have it loop until it can successfully see the value. This will fail (and loop forever) if an error occurred in the `COMMIT` which could not be sent back to the client before the timeout expired, but less probable. This is a lot of work just to make something unreliable less unreliable, though.

Comment: If your application has full control over the T-SQL it sends (using separate commands) you could also conceivably issue the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` statements explicitly (instead of using `SqlTransaction`). Then you can set the `CommandTimeout` of the `COMMIT` statement to 0, giving it as much time as it needs. Again, an ugly solution to make something unreliable work.

Comment: The idea about using `SqlTransaction` is to call few stored procedures with the same transaction. Ok, you can say that I can create new stored procedure, that calls the other ones, but it will solve only single place in code. I am worried, that it might happen in different place. We've fixed that issue by updating DB entry manually. I can accept that solution only if it is vary rare scenario and for now I will keep it like that. I understand that there is no good solution.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar/same problem. The COMMIT command operation took very long and client (python) timed out in the meantime.
This can occur if there are [DTC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/distributed-transaction-coordinator-dtc?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal) waits in the database. In our case it was caused by overloading database's tempDB from another process, that was run from service broker. This caused DTC to overload and prolonged COMMIT operations significantly.
At the end we didn't find solution on client side - so theoretically the problem still persists, but it doesn't happen anymore if we keep an eye on DTC wait types in DB processes.